# Child component need to be called after parent get mounted with its styles in Aphrodite/Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a structure where my **Parent Component (Layout)**(Presentational Component) will render the DOM which has a **child component (Fitme)** which will get the scroll height and client to check whether the child is overflowing or not, and reduce/increase the font size.

As React doc says, Parent did mount will be called after all child. So my fitme component gets executed before parent do the paint. It makes child to not work as expected.

Requirement: As I want the Child to be plug-able, i dont want to pass any property in props from parent to notify the child about the mount state.

**Edited**: Please find the sandbox link. 
For the First time (after load), it will not be fitting the text. but if you change the dom, so that it will rerender the component. it will work.

[**https://codesandbox.io/s/k2051pwl83**](https://codesandbox.io/s/k2051pwl83)

**Update**: I guess this is the issue with the plugin i am using to apply css in js way (aphrodite). not sure about it, but i have raise a ticket in git. and code is update in the sandbox.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: pls provide a codepen or jsfiddle

Comment: @anu: please check the sandbox link.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is nothing related to React. React does its job to the best. I should have not doubted React.

This issue is related to **Aphrodite**. It uses [asap](https://github.com/kriskowal/asap) to to schedule buffer flushing. 
As doc says in caveats section,

> If you measure DOM elements' dimensions in **componentDidMount** or **componentDidUpdate**, you can use setTimeout or flushToStyleTag to ensure all styles are injected.

So i have to add setTimeout in **componentDidMount** or **componentDidUpdate**.

Here is the updated CodeSandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/4364jvm7q9